# Auto resize cells to fill screen without removing cells

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Let's say I have 1 row and 2 columns. Both have a video stream which will automatically resize to fill what it can, so they both take half the screen.

I want to be able to remove one stream and have the second fill the entire screen. So basically, have the second cell push to fill the entire screen since nothing is occupying the first cell to "push it" back.

I know I can do this by removing cells, but it would be many times cleaner, simpler, and easier if there were some setting to accomplish what I am describing.

EDIT:

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

I start with only one of each and expand dynamically from there by doing:

```
                if (grd.ColumnDefinitions.Count == grd.RowDefinitions.Count)
                {
                    System.Windows.Controls.ColumnDefinition newColumn;
                    newColumn = new System.Windows.Controls.ColumnDefinition();
                    grd.ColumnDefinitions.Add(newColumn);
                    Column = grd.ColumnDefinitions.Count - 1;
                    Row = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Windows.Controls.RowDefinition newRow;
                    newRow = new System.Windows.Controls.RowDefinition();
                    grd.RowDefinitions.Add(newRow);
                    Row = grd.RowDefinitions.Count - 1;
                    Column = 0;
                }
```

Comment: Can you share how your columns/rows are defined in XAML?

Comment: You must add four spaces in front of your XAML code, otherwise stackoverflow will interpret it as an HTML literal and attempt to either render it or discard it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `Width` of the `GridViewColumn` to `0` and the `Visibility` of the container control (either the view stream control itself or its container) to `Collapsed`.

**EDIT**
Although a [`UniformGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.aspx) might be easier to work with. Then you'd only need to set the visibility of the control to collapsed (which will remove that control from the width calculation).

I'd recommend setting the UniformGrid's `Rows` property to `1` to keep everything on a single line (otherwise it will begin a process of alternately adding rows and columns).

```
<UniformGrid Rows="1">
    <Grid Visibility="{Binding IsVideo1Visible, Converter={BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <abc:VideoStream>
    </Grid>
    <abc:VideoStream Visibility="{Binding IsVideo2Visible, Converter={BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
</UniformGrid>
```

*Use the above code for inspiration. The first video stream control is wrapped in a Grid simply to demonstrate how you might "add" the visibility property if the control you are using does not expose one. It is completely optional.*

Comment: With proper column/row XAML markup, wouldn't the columnwidth shrink to 0 automatically upon setting the container control's Visibility to Collapsed?

Comment: @JonathanPiché - Not necessarily. If the width is set to "*", then the column will still occupy space, even if it contains nothing. I've used this technique for some of my layouts.

Comment: In that case, setting the ColumnWidth to "Auto" instead of "*" should do the trick.

Comment: @JonathanPiché - Yep. "Auto" or "0". But the OP specifically said that the columns each fill half the screen which, to me, suggests the column width has been set to "*". "0" simply ensures that the column will not be visible even if the control (or its container) is still visible.

Comment: Setting the video object to Visibility.Collapsed simply makes it not visible. The object isn't my own and belongs to a SDK I'm using, so I guess I can't really work around that.

Setting height/width to 0 does just that, and nothing can be seen :)

Thanks guys, due to the object I think I may have to remove the cells.

Comment: You propose changing the ColumnWidth to 0 through code when setting the Visibility to Collapsed. What I suggest is rather to set the Width to Auto in the XAML directly in the source and not changing it afterwards.

Comment: @IanDubya - you tried setting the ***GridViewColumn's*** width to 0? Or just the video stream?

Comment: The grid, I did not set the stream's height/width, was that what you were referring to?

Comment: @JonathanPiché - The GridViewColumn's Width property is a dependency property, meaning it can use databinding. You could easily create a style which responds to some *state* property which could set the appropriate values.

Comment: @IanDubya - The *Grid*, or the *GridViewColumn*? In your code sample, you are setting the GridViewColumn's Width property to "*", which means it will take up half the screen whether it has content or not.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to wrap both video streams into a single StackPanel within your grid. Then, setting the video control's Visibility to Collapsed would provide the functionality you're looking for.

However StackPanels do remove a good chunk of the "autosizing" magic of WPF since they have infinite width and height, but in some situations it's an easy solution.

Comment: Stack Panels would make it extremely difficult to have each video stream fill exactly half the screen, as the OP has said. (And the video stream would not expand to fill the screen when the other has been hidden.)